# Characteristics of matrix skew hermitian

Tags: matrices

If $A$ matrix is element of matrix skew hermitian so $<Ax,y> = <x,A^Ty>$ for each $x,y$ are elements of matrix complex with order nx1. Is there anyone here who knows what is the meaning of < and > on this problem?

And why in the picture the step is we should time multiply between each element of the left matrix and each element of the right matrix.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

$<\cdot,\cdot >$ is called the [inner product](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InnerProduct.html), and is a generalization of the usual [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product):

$$\vec a\cdot \vec b=\sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i$$

and so the page is using an alternative notation to the dot product.

The multiplication given is a bit weird, I would write:

$$
(a_{11}ix_1+a_{12}x_2+\dots+a_{1n}x_n)y_1+\\
(a_{21}x_1+a_{22}ix_2+\dots+a_{2n}x_n)y_2+\\
\vdots\\
(a_{n1}x_1+a_{n2}x_2+\dots+a_{nn}ix_n)y_n
$$

Collecting by $x_i$ gives the relation given.